# Mui Tabs - How to use custom icons

Tags: reactjs, svg, tabs, material-ui

I'm new to mui and react in general, and I have 2 questions.

1. I'm trying to use my own SVG files as custom icons in a mui tab, but can't figure out how exactly to do that (with all the effects as using mui icon).

my code:

```
import { ReactComponent as SecondIcon } from "../../images/tabs/secondTab.svg";
import { ReactComponent as ThirdIcon } from "../../images/tabs/thirdTab.svg";
import { ReactComponent as FourthIcon } from "../../images/tabs/fourthTab.svg";
import FirstTabSvg from "../../images/svg/FirstTabSvg";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 500,
    width: 80,
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  margin: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  tab: {
    width: 80,
  },
  imageIcon: {
    height: '100%'
  },
  iconRoot: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
}));

export default function IconTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };


  return (
    <Paper square className={classes.root}>
      <IconButton color="primary" size="small" className={classes.margin}>
        <LogoIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Divider variant="middle" style={{ alignSelf: "stretch" }} />

      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        // variant="fullWidth"
        width="auto"
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        aria-label="icon tabs example"
        orientation="vertical"
      >
        <Tab icon={<FirstTabSvg />} aria-label="first" />
        <Tab icon={<SecondIcon />} aria-label="second" />
        <Tab icon={<ThirdIcon />} aria-label="third" />
        <Tab icon={<FourthIcon />} aria-label="fourth" />
      </Tabs>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

I've tried 2 options (import as ReactComponent & SvgIcon with src)

FirstTabSvg.js (saw this as an answer in another question):

```
import React from 'react';
import pure from 'recompose/pure';
import { SvgIcon } from '@material-ui/core';

let FirstTabSvg = (props) => (
  <SvgIcon {...props}>
    <img src="../tabs/firstTab.svg" />
  </SvgIcon>
);
FirstTabSvg = pure(FirstTabSvg);
FirstTabSvg.displayName = 'FirstTabSvg';
FirstTabSvg.muiName = 'SvgIcon';

export default FirstTabSvg;
```

result:

[Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENo6z.png)

as you can see, the `FirstTabSvg` does not render, and the `ReactComponent` does render but I don't know how to change the color for an active tab.

2. how can I change the tabs width? as you can see in the picture, the indicator is not in the same line as the tabs